# Phone numbers in php

Tags: php, sql, forms, phone-number

I have a website and it gathers user information. The registry form asks for a phone number or email. The user enters their phone number as a `$_POST` variable. I need to be able to identify the Mobile Carrier by the number that the user entered. It looks something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['tel'])) {
   $tel     = $_POST['tel'];
   $tel_fin = $tel."@txt."$carrier_url; 
}
```

Where `$tel` is the phone number & `$carrier_url` is the URL of the carriers website(ex. att.com). The Format in which you send a message to a mobile phone number looks like this: 1235557777@txt.att.com .How can I get the carrier's URL from the phone number entered by the user?

Comment: Scanned from where? Return the URL how, can you clarify?

Comment: I sense two errors so far

Comment: So, you're trying to get their phone number, figure out who the carrier is and then send them a text message??

Comment: If this isn't pseudo-code, then I'm the King of Persia. Say it ain't so Joe, say it ain't so!

Comment: I guess the OP wasn't kidding => *"It looks **something** like this"*

Comment: Yes, exactly 'relentless'

Answer (score 0):

Here in The Phillipines, every carriers has their respective number coding.. like 0906 company A, 0918 company B, 0921 Company C, etc etc.
So to make it work properly, first gather the necessary data and put it in a table..

```
$array_of_numbers = Array('0908' => CompanyA, '0907' => CompanyB, '0916' => CompanyC);
$first_4_number = substr($_POST['tel'], 0, 4);

$carrier = array_key_exists($first_4_number, $array_of_numbers) ? $array_of_numbers[$first_4_number] : false;

if($carrier){
   $tel     = $_POST['tel'];
   $tel_fin = $tel."@txt."$carrier;
}
```